# Restangular Nested Rest Resources inside Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, rest, restangular

My services

```
app.factory('PartnerServiceRestangular', ['Restangular', function(Restangular) {

    return Restangular.service('partner');

}]);

app.factory('PartnerInvoiceServiceRestangular', ['PartnerServiceRestangular', function(PartnerServiceRestangular) {

    return PartnerServiceRestangular.one('partner', partnerId).service('invoice');

}]);
```

My Controller

```
app.controller('FinancialsController', [
    '$scope',
    'PartnerServiceRestangular',
    'PartnerInvoiceServiceRestangular',
    function($scope, PartnerServiceRestangular, PartnerInvoiceServiceRestangular) {

    PartnerServiceRestangular.getList().then(function(partners) {
        $scope.partners = partners;
    });

    $scope.partnerChange = function(partner) {
        $scope.partner = partner;
    };

    var getInvoices = function(partnerId, startDate, stopDate) {

        // STUCK HERE
        PartnerInvoiceServiceRestangular.get({})    
    };
```

What I am looking to do is to allow `PartnerInvoiceServiceRestangular` to perform the following get requests:

- `/partner/{partnerId}/invoice/` - To return ALL invoices for a specific partnerId
- `/partner/{partnerId}/invoice/?startDate=2014-06-01&stopDate=2014-6-30` - Return all invoices between 2 given dates
- `/partner/{partnerId}/invoice/{invoiceId}` - To return a specific invoice

I already have the ng-models setup in the view which set the $scopes of `partnerId`, `startDate`, `stopDate`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

```
app.factory('PartnerInvoiceServiceRestangular', ['PartnerServiceRestangular', function(PartnerServiceRestangular) {

    return {
        getService: function(partnerId) {
             PartnerServiceRestangular.one('partner', partnerId).service('invoice');
        }
    }

}]);


var getInvoices = function(partnerId, startDate, stopDate) {
    PartnerInvoiceServiceRestangular.getService(partnerId)
       .getList({ startDate: startDate, stopDate: stopDate }).then(function(invoices) {
            $scope.partner.invoices = invoices;
       }
};
```

However I'm not a fan of your factory service implementation. Why not just use:

```
$scope.partnerChange = function(partner) {
    $scope.partner = partner;
    partner.getList('invoice', { startDate: startDate, stopDate: stopDate }).then(function(invoices) {
            $scope.partner.invoices = invoices;
       });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer.

Let's have a look at "Decoupled Restangular Service" section: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#decoupled-restangular-service

**We can also use Nested RESTful resources with this:**

```
var Cars = Restangular.service('cars', Restangular.one('users', 1));

Cars.getList() // GET to /users/1/cars
```

In your case it's gonna be like this:

```
var partner = PartnerServiceRestangular.one(1);
var invoices = Restangular.service('invoice', partner);
```

But not sure about your `PartnerInvoiceServiceRestangular` factory designed well.

Hope this helps.